# ASP.NET / IIS loading X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to load a certificate in a class that is hosted in IIS.

The code that i used is:

```
  X509Certificate2 privateCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Temp\file.pfx", "mycertpass");
```

Later on in my code when privateCertificate is used it causes a problem on the production environment. This problem does not occur on the local environment, the exception is as follows:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: CryptographicException 
    Exception message: An internal error occurred.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at Medapp.PaymentResponse.CreateRepository()
   at Medapp.PaymentResponse.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I thought it might be a permission on folder problem however i have added "everyone" with full access temporarily and this did not solve the problem either.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure `C:\Temp\file.pfx` path is accesible. probably you want to test `Server.MapPath("~/folder/" + filename)`.
- Also check out the identity of your app pool and make sure that the `Load user profile` option is turned on, otherwise the crypto susbsystem won't work.
- Try specifying X509KeyStorageFlags

  var certificate = new X509Certificate2(KeyFilePath, KeyFilePassword,
     X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
     X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
     X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This helped me fix app pool crashes when calling LoadCertificateFromFile.

Comment: I had a crunch-time all-nighter and demo, that I ended up being late for cuz of this issue.  #2 on this list saved my life!